# Start Redis inside Docker container with Redis dump without compose

Tags: docker, redis

I'm a **complete beginner** to Docker and I've been tasked with creating a containerized Redis instance and a containerized web application to pull a random value from the database without using compose.

So far I've created a bridge network and containerized the application and the Redis instance, and this works fine. However, no matter what I seem to do, the Redis instance is always empty (dbsize=0). So far I've instanced Redis with

```
docker run --detach --name redis-ins -v /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb redis:latest
```

as suggested by someone on GitHub, but as explained above, that doesn't seem to work. The path to the file is correct, as a Redis instance running on the physical machine is fine and has all the values.

So my question is, do I need to use a Dockerfile instead to create the instance? I'm reiterating here that I am not allowed to use Docker Compose. Any pointer(s) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems maybe the volume is not set correctly ? can you try `docker run --detach --name redis-ins -v /redis_data:/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb redis:latest`  and also to add here some redis logs ? when i entered the container you created i see it created `dump.rdb` as a directory not as a file

Comment: @BatchenRegev You're correct, I actually had to provide the argument -v as a directory instead with :/data added to the end. Thank you.